# Can not connect to Database outside vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Hey I have lambda inside of vpc, I try to connect to the mongodb outside of my vpc, the thing is the outbound connection seems to be blocked. Because when I put the lambda outside of VPC then the connection is working. Below I am posting VPC outbound rules, for my understanding the are responsible for the connections goind out of the lambda. This is the default VPC so it has internet gatway set etc. Looks like there is something I do not understand ... ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions deployed inside a VPC are never assigned a public IP address. Because of this they cannot use an internet gateway directly. Lambda functions inside a VPC have no direct access to anything outside of the VPC. If you want a Lambda function running inside a VPC to access a MongoDB instance running somewhere outside of the VPC, then you will have to configure VPC subnets with NAT Gateways, and then configure the Lambda function to run inside those subnets.

Comment: mongo has open connections for all ranges. I did this already once but the setup is gone, so its possibl. The nat gateway is a solution when we would like to restrict inbound on mongo server for specific ip

Comment: @filemonczyk Your comment makes no sense. Your problem is entirely related to the Lambda function being blocked from accessing things outside of the VPC. The Lambda function literally has no internet connection, because it can't use the internet gateway directly, so it is never going to get out of the VPC without a NAT gateway.